# Mount error while trying to connect encrypted AWS EFS with efs-csi-node in EKS

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-efs

I have tried connecting unencrypted EFS and it is working fine, but with encrypted EFS, the pod is throwing below error:

```sh
  Normal   Scheduled    10m                    default-scheduler                                     Successfully assigned default/jenkins-efs-test-8ffb4dc86-xnjdj to ip-10-100-4-249.ap-south-1.compute.internal
  Warning  FailedMount  6m33s (x2 over 8m49s)  kubelet, ip-10-100-4-249.ap-south-1.compute.internal  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[jenkins-home], unattached volumes=[sc-config-volume tmp jenkins-home jenkins-config secrets-dir plugins plugin-dir jenkins-efs-test-token-7nmkz]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  4m19s                  kubelet, ip-10-100-4-249.ap-south-1.compute.internal  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[jenkins-home], unattached volumes=[plugins plugin-dir jenkins-efs-test-token-7nmkz sc-config-volume tmp jenkins-home jenkins-config secrets-dir]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  2m2s                   kubelet, ip-10-100-4-249.ap-south-1.compute.internal  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[jenkins-home], unattached volumes=[tmp jenkins-home jenkins-config secrets-dir plugins plugin-dir jenkins-efs-test-token-7nmkz sc-config-volume]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  35s (x13 over 10m)     kubelet, ip-10-100-4-249.ap-south-1.compute.internal  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "efs-pv" : kubernetes.io/csi: mounter.SetupAt failed: rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not mount "" at "/var/lib/kubelet/pods/354800a1-dcf5-4812-aa91-0e84ca6fba59/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/efs-pv/mount": mount failed: exit status 1
Mounting command: mount
Mounting arguments: -t efs /var/lib/kubelet/pods/354800a1-dcf5-4812-aa91-0e84ca6fba59/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/efs-pv/mount
Output: mount: /var/lib/kubelet/pods/354800a1-dcf5-4812-aa91-0e84ca6fba59/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/efs-pv/mount: can't find in /etc/fstab.
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what the K8s manifests are or any configuration. [There shouldn't be any difference between encrypted and non-encrypted volumes when it comes to mounting from the client-side](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs.html#mounting-access-points). In essence, AWS manages the encryption keys for you using [KMS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/encryption-at-rest.html).

The error you are seeing is basically because [the mount command is not specifying the mount point](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771473/mount-cant-find-device-in-etc-fstab) so there must have been some other default configuration from the K8s side that you are changing when using un-encrypted EFS volumes. Also, is the [EFS Mount helper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/installing-amazon-efs-utils.html) available on the Kubernetes node where you are trying to mount the EFS Volume?

✌️

Comment: I didn't changed any mount configurations in yaml files for encrypted volume, and I have tried with efs provisioner and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs of the cloud init agent (`/var/logs/cloud-init.log` and `/var/logs/cloud-init-output.log`) if the EFS filesystem mount does not work as expected. Check [/etc/fstab](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/9.1-rc1/chapter08/fstab.html) file.

Try to  update efs-csi-node daemonset from `amazon/aws-efs-csi-driver:v0.3.0` image to `amazon/aws-efs-csi-driver:latest`.

Here is example mounting [EFS script](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/05/03/sharing-efs-filesystem-ecs/). Compare it to yours and note that:

**Dependencies for this script:**

- Default ECS cluster configuration (Amazon Linux ECS  [AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html)).
- The ECS instance must have a IAM role that gives it at least read access to EFS (in order to locate the EFS filesystem ID).
- The ECS instance must be in a security group that allows port tcp/2049 (NFS) inbound/outbound.
- The security group that the ECS instance belongs to must be associated with the target EFS filesystem.

**Notes on this script:**

- The EFS mount path is calculated on a per-instance basis as the EFS endpoint varies depending upon the region and availability zone where the instance is launched.
- The EFS mount is added to  `/etc/fstab`  so that if the ECS instance is rebooted, the mount point will be re-created.
- Docker is restarted to ensure it correctly detects the EFS filesystem mount.

Restart docker after mounting EFS with command:  `$ service docker restart`. At the end try to reboot the EKS worker node.

Take a look: [mounting-efs-in-eks-cluster-example-deployment-fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62447132/mounting-efs-in-eks-cluster-example-deployment-fails/62458759#62458759), [efs-provisioner](https://www.eksworkshop.com/beginner/190_efs/efs-provisioner/), [dynamic-ip-in-etc-fstab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250660/dynamic-ip-in-etc-fstab).